# [Kubernetes]- How to limit a user to only delete namespaces that have been dynamically created by the user?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I want to create a user that has permission to create temporary namespaces (i.e. create and then delete the namespaces) and have full access within these namespaces only, and without being able to delete any other namespaces within the cluster. My problem is that the namespaces in this case are created dynamically by the user with a random name each time...is there any way to meet this requirement for a user to:

- Create namespace (with a random name that is only known after execution)
- Have full access to this name space only
- Able to delete this namespace only

Answer (score 0):

On my understanding there is no way to accomplish this kind of permissions - I know it's surprising because it would seem like a common use case. Using Roles, the rules only apply to the namespace the role belongs to, using an appropriate RoleBinding. Therefore we can limit actions on specific namespaces, but we cannot define a permission on a namespace with unknown name. Also using regex is not supported to match namespaces names. To solve it with Roles,  we would have to apply the role every time a new namespace is created, I think makes no sense for the use case.

As you may know Kubernetes also defines cluster roles and cluster role bindings. Those are similar to normal roles but without a namespace limitation. Of course, using them in this case can break through the isolation we  want, that's what they are meant to do.

What I suggest is to predefine a list of namespaces for which those accounts will have permissions. That means you need to create/use the same namespaces and to not generate them dinamically with random names. It also means that it will not be able to create new namespaces.

Lastly, I wanted to mention [Hierarchical Namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/08/14/introducing-hierarchical-namespaces/). Under HNS, administrators can organize tenants according to a group hierarchy and allocate capabilities accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You can first restrict user to create/delete resources only in the namespace using a `Role` bind that role to the user.

Then you can use `ClusterRole` with only access to the namespaces resource and allow it to create, delete, etc.

`ClusterRole` and  `Role` define which resources you can operate on. If your role needs to manage resources in multiple namespaces, you need to use ClusterRole
and `RoleBinding` defines which namespace your account will be granted

Example:

Create a `Role` in the namespace that can be used to grant access to resources.

```
kind: Role
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    namespace: namespace1
    name: user-namespace-role
  rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["services", "endpoints", "pods"] # etc...
    verbs: ["get", "list", "create",”delete”] # etc
```

Then execute the below command which creates `rolebinding` that defines which namespace your account will be granted.

```
 $  kubectl create rolebinding user-namespace-binding --role=user-namespace-role --user=<user-name> --namespace=namespace1
```

Now Create a `ClusterRole` that can be used to grant access in any particular namespace, or across all namespaces

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cluster-role-all-namespaces
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["namespaces"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"] # etc
```

Then Execute the below command to create `clusterrolebinding`:

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding all-namespaces-binding --clusterrole=cluster-role-all-namespaces --user=<username>
```

Refer to [Using RBAC authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) for more information.

Comment: The question is about "delete this namespace only" not all namespaces...